# Aggregate Key/Value from Dictionaries in PyMongo

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of documents that look like:

```
{
  "id": 45,
  "some_list": [{"x": 1, "y": {"a": 10, "b": 32, "c": 91}}, 
                {"x": 2, "y": {"a": 12, "b": 26, "d": 75, "p": 1}}]
}
```

or

```
{
  "id": 119,
  "some_list": [{"x": 1, "y": {"a": 5}}, 
                {"x": 2, "y": {"b": 60, "p": 8}}]
}
```

I'd like to retrieve an aggregated result that sums all of the `y` dictionaries. And get:

```
{"a": 27, "b": 118, "c": 91, "d": 75, "p": 9}

# a = 10 + 12 + 5
# b = 32 + 26 + 60
# c = 91
# d = 75
# p = 1 + 8
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
pipeline = [
    {"$unwind": "$some_list"},
    {"$group": {"_id": "$some_list.y.key", "count": {"$sum": "$some_list.y.value"}}},
]
list(client.db.collection.aggregate(pipeline))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below aggregation

Since you have unknown keys you have to use [**`$objectToArray`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) to convert dynamic keys into `k` and `v` format then you can easily [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) them.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$some_list" },
  { "$addFields": {
    "some_list": { "$objectToArray": "$some_list.y" }
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$some_list" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$some_list.k",
    "count": { "$sum": "$some_list.v" }
  }}
])
```

Output

```
[
  { "_id": "c", "count": 91 },
  { "_id": "d", "count": 75 },
  { "_id": "p", "count": 9 },
  { "_id": "b", "count": 118 },
  { "_id": "a", "count": 27 }
]
```

And even if you want the data in key value pair then you can use this

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$some_list" },
  { "$addFields": {
    "some_list": { "$objectToArray": "$some_list.y" }
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$some_list" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$some_list.k",
    "count": { "$sum": "$some_list.v" }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "data": { "$push": { "k": "$_id", "v": "$count" }}
  }},
  { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": { "$arrayToObject": "$data" }}}
])
```

Output

```
[
  {
    "a": 27,
    "b": 118,
    "c": 91,
    "d": 75,
    "p": 9
  }
]
```

Comment: Should `null` be `"null"`?

Comment: I'm getting an "Oversize document being created error" in the second code example

Comment: Nopes. `null` with double quotes will be a string. So it should be a `null`

Comment: Re: `null`, I don't think this works for PyMongo. Re: documents, I have a couple of million but each dictionary of key/value pairs could be in the 10K+ and the keys can differ significantly across the documents. Cumulatively, there are about 4-5 million different keys

Comment: The error is not with the `null` expression. It is just saying that you cannot  `$push` the million number of  documents in the `$group` stage inside an array because of the 16MB of mongo BSON limit. So instead you should go with the first one.

Comment: maybe I'm missing something but I'm not aware that `null` is valid syntax in PyMongo (Python).

Comment: You can use "FALSE" as well instead of `null`

Comment: Pretty sure you can also use `None` in pymongo as a `null` equivalent.